# How to get a Table of pairs (a/b, c/d) where GCD[a,b]==1 and GCD[c,d]==1?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, filtering

I am trying to make a Table pairs of (a/b, c/d) where `GCD[a,b]==1` and `GCD[c,d]==1`. I have tried the following:

```
Table[{{a/b, c/d}}, {a, 1, 6}, {b, 1, 6}, {c, 1, 4}, {d, 1, 4}]
```

Trying the following doesn't help:

```
Table[{{a/b, c/d}}, {a, 1, 6}, {b, 1, 6}, {c, 1, 4}, {d, 1, 4}, GCD[a, b] == 1, GCD[c, d] == 1]
```

How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sol = Solve[{GCD[a, b] == 1, GCD[c, d] == 1, 1 <= a <= 6, 1 <= b <= 6,
     1 <= c <= 6, 1 <= d <= 4}, Integers];
{a/b, c/d} /. sol
```

Answer (score 5):

This may need to be rethought if you want to search a large number of integers. You could start by finding relatively prime pairs within some range:

```
relativelyPrimePairs = Select[Tuples[Range@6, 2], Apply[CoprimeQ]]
```

Now you can take all pairs of those:

```
Tuples[relativelyPrimePairs, 2]
```

Then you can make fractions:

```
Map[Apply[Divide], Tuples[relativelyPrimePairs, 2], {-2}]
```

I notice that your example uses fewer samples for the second fraction, so we could filter that list:

```
Map[
  Apply[Divide], 
  Tuples[{relativelyPrimePairs, Select[relativelyPrimePairs, AllTrue[LessEqualThan[4]]]}], {-2}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this by adding an If in the Table:

```
Select[Flatten[Table[If[GCD[a, b] == 1 && GCD[c, d] == 1, 
   {a/b, c/d}], {a, 1, 6}, {b, 1, 6}, {c, 1, 4}, {d, 1, 4}], 3], # =!= Null &]
```

The Flatten removes all the extra parentheses and the Select removes all the ones that do not fulfill the condition.

Answer (score 4):

```
Do[
    If[CoprimeQ[a, b] && CoprimeQ[c, d],
        Sow[{a / b, c / d}]
    ]
    ,
    {a, 1, 6}
    ,
    {b, 1, 6}
    ,
    {c, 1, 4}
    ,
    {d, 1, 4}
] //
Reap //
#[[2]]& //
First
```

Comment: You can replace `// #[[2]]& // First` by `// #[[2,1]]&`. And to be honest you can replace that by `(Do[...]//Reap)[[2,1]]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
t = Table[{{a, b, c, d}}, {a, 1, 6}, {b, 1, 6}, {c, 1, 4}, {d, 1, 
     4}] // Flatten[#, 4] &;
t2 = (t /. {a_, b_, c_, d_} :>  
     If[CoprimeQ[a, b] && CoprimeQ[c, d], {{a, b, c, d}, a/b, c/d}, 
      Nothing]);
Length /@ {t, t2}
```

> {576, 253}

To see this in a grid format:

```
t2 // Grid
```

Answer (score 3):

Just another way using [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html)

```
helper = Function[u, Union@Catenate[{#1/#2, #2/#1} & @@@ u]];
c6 = RelationGraph[CoprimeQ, Range[6]] // EdgeList;
c4 = RelationGraph[CoprimeQ, Range[4]] // EdgeList;
Tuples[{helper[c6], helper[c4]}]
```

`helper` just tidies up coprime pairs from each range

`c4`, `c6` are just coprime pairs in relevant range

The last line is result sorted.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[coprimePairRatios]

coprimePairRatios = Tuples @*
  Map[{Array[If[CoprimeQ @ ##, #/#2, Nothing] &, #, 1, Sequence]} &];

Length @ coprimePairRatios @ {{6, 6}, {4, 4}}
```

> ```
> 253
> ```

```
Short[coprimePairRatios @ {{6, 6}, {4, 4}}, 3]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 3):

Some other approaches using [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) and [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html):

```
t = Tuples[{Range[6], Range[6], Range[4], Range[4]}];
res1 = True /. 
   GroupBy[t, (CoprimeQ[#[[1]], #[[2]]]) && 
       CoprimeQ[#[[3]], #[[4]]] & -> ({#[[1]]/#[[2]], #[[3]]/#[[4]]} \
&)];
res2 = {#1/#2, #3/#4} & @@@ 
   Pick[t, (CoprimeQ[#[[1]], #[[2]]]) && CoprimeQ[#[[3]], #[[4]]] & /@
      t];`
```